# Get the bounding rect for an element outside of a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Inside a directive I want to get the result of `getBoundingClientRect()` for a DOM element that is no where near the `element` of the directive.

How should I go about this? Service that just returns that object? Is it OK to have DOM logic in a service?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest passing the id of the element the directive needs to interact with as an attribute to the directive.  Then use the document object to get a handle to that element.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/afX63/6/.

You'll obviously need to work directly with the raw DOM element to access the information you're interested in.

Your markup:

```
<my-directive handle-id="thatOne"/>

<div id="thatOne">Your directive can find this element easily now</div>
```

You directive:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            var theHandle = angular.element(document.getElementById(attrs.handleId));
            theHandle.text('Changed it');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I thought of passing in a selector, however if there are many instances of the same directive, each one will query the DOM uselessly. I only want to ask once and get the bounding rectangle which doesn't change after the first query.